# Trying to get OSM ID, city, county, state and other details into one file (JSON or CSV)

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr2ogr

In order to get a couple of details about cities (including lat/lon and Wikipedia link - if available) into a file per country, I found and followed this tutorial: https://journocode.com/en/tutorials/extracting-geodata-from-openstreetmap-with-osmfilter/

So the first step is to download a country - that works well.
And then I'd convert the file, filter and I've got my export.

```
osmconvert austria.pbf -o=austria.o5m
osmfilter austria.o5m --keep="place=city =town =village" --drop-author --drop-version -o=austria_all_towns.osm
ogr2ogr -skipfailures  -f CSV "output_all_towns.csv" austria_all_towns.osm
```

Inside my CSV (or JSON) export I'll have data looking like this:

```
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "osm_id": "227388938", "name": "Braunfels", "place": ...
```

If I try to confirm / get details about the data now on Nominatim, I receive an empty response array (due to a wrong OSM ID as it seems):

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/lookup?osm_ids=R227388938&format=json

If I use OSM IDs from other sources, I receive a proper JSON via the nominatim lookup.

Do I have two different IDs from two different systems here?
How do I get what I'm looking for from the country download file? (all on Linux, in case that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

227388938 is the ID of the [*node* Braunfels](https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/227388938) but you told Nominatim to lookup the OSM ID of a *relation*. Replace `R` with `N` in your call to Nominatim and you will get the correct result: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/lookup?osm_ids=N227388938&format=json

Note that OSM has three different [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements): nodes, ways and relations. IDs are only unique within one element type. This means, there are nodes, ways and relations of the *same* ID but with a completely different meaning. You always have to specify the correct element type when specifying an OSM ID.

Comment: Oh - that was easy, thank you very much. :)